# Rudin Theorem 4.4: Properties of continuous functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

This is a proof that Rudin left as an exercise, but I was hoping someone could look over my attempt.

> Suppose $E \subset X$, a metric space, $p$ is a limit point of $E$, $f$ and $g$ are complex functions on $E$, and
> \begin{align*}
> \lim\limits_{x \to p} f(x) = A, \; \lim\limits_{x \to p} g(x) = B.
> \end{align*}
> Then
> (a) $\lim\limits_{x \to p} (f + g)(x) = A + B$;

> (b) $\lim\limits_{x \to p} (fg)(x) = AB$;

> (c)  $\lim\limits_{x \to p} \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x) = \frac{A}{B}$, if $B \neq 0$.

Here is my attempt.

> As $\lim\limits_{x \to p} f(x) = A$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to p} g(x) = B$, by Theorem 4.2, for any sequence $\{p_n\}$ in $E$ such that $p_n \neq p$ and $p_n \to p$, we $f(p_n) \to A$ and $g(p_n) \to B$. But then $f(p_n) + g(p_n) = (f + g)(p_n) \to A + B$ by Theorem 3.3(a), so by Theorem 4.2, we have $\lim\limits_{x \to p} (f + g)(x) = A + B$. This proves (a) By Theorem 3.3(b), we have $fg(p_n) = f(p_n) g(p_n) \to AB$, so by Theorem 4.2, we have $\lim\limits_{x \to p} (fg)(x) = AB$. By Theorem 3.3(d), assuming that $p_n \neq 0$ for any $n$ and $B \neq 0$, we have $\frac{1}{p_n} \to \frac{1}{B}$. Then, by Theorem 3.3(c) with $s_n = f(p_n)$ and $t_n = \frac{1}{p_n}$, we have $f(p_n) \cdot \frac{1}{p_n} = \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(p_n) = \frac{A}{B}$, proving (c).

I have a few doubts:

(1) He defines $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ for functions, but not for 'functional sequences.' (In fact, the notion that $f(x_n)$ is itself a sequence is almost posited axiomatically, but I accept it, since a sequence is a function $\mathbb{N} \to A$, and mapping to some other space prior doesn't change that.) Am I correct that $f(x_n) + g(x_n) = (f + g)(x_n)$, and this is nothing more than a definition of $f+g$?

(2) In part (c), he assumes $B \neq 0$, but not that the sequence $p_n$ is never $0$. I have to insert this in order to talk about a quotient $\frac{1}{p_n}$. Doesn't that sacrifice generality? Or, if $p_n = 0$, then the sequence $\frac{1}{p_n}$ doesn't even exist, so it doesn't count in the definition of "every sequence with this property"?

(c) Rudin never defined a quotient of functions, but I assume the most reasonable definition I can take for granted is $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Is that right? I'm also supposing, perhaps on a leap, that I can treat a quotient of functions as a product: namely, ${f(x)}{g(x)} = f(x) \cdot \frac{1}{g(x)}$. Is that ok?

Comment: I'll just comment on the $B\ne0$ part. Since the limit exists and is nonzero, you can find some neighborhood of $p$ such that $g(q)\ne0$ for all $q$ in that neighborhood. Maybe add that to your proof, rather than just assuming $p_n\ne0$.

Comment: So is the idea that limits are a 'local' property, so if I can find such a neighborhood, it suffices to consider just it? I think I need to prove a few lemmas to demonstrate this, but the argument makes sense.

Comment: I think that might be a good way to think about it, but I guess I think about it in the sense that any fixed, finite number of terms of a sequence has no impact on the limit of the sequence. If $p_n \to p$, then for any open neighborhood of $p$, there are only finitely many terms of $p_n$ outside of the neighborhood.

Comment: This makes more sense. Last question: can you help me prove from the definition that there exists such a neighborhood? It makes sense to me in $\mathbb{R}$ with the absolute-value metric and geometrically, but I don't know if I can prove it with an arbitrary metric.

Comment: I am not sure what definition Rudin uses, but really the definition of a limit in any metric space (maybe it has to have some properties like connected, or closed, etc. ) is the same as in $\mathbb{R}$, but instead of saying: $$\forall\epsilon>0, \, \exists N, \, \forall n>N, \, \left| p - p_n \right| < \epsilon$$We say:$$\forall\epsilon>0, \, \exists N, \, \forall n>N, \, \operatorname{d}\left( p, p_n \right) < \epsilon$$Since the limit is $B\ne0$, the usual choice of $\epsilon$ would be $|B|/2$, i.e. half the distance between $B$ and 0, although any positive value less than $|B|$ would work.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about this incorrectly. So $\lim\limits_{x \to p} g(x) = B \neq 0$, so given $\epsilon = \frac{|B|}{2} > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $0 < d(x,p) < \delta$ implies $d(g(x), B) < \frac{|B|}{2}$. But I don't see how that guarantees that $g$ is non-zero in this neighborhood, however.

Comment: I thought you were showing that for any arbitrary, fixed sequence $p_n\to p$, $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(p_n)\to\frac{A}{B}$, so the definition that I gave for limit in my comment shows that since $g(p_n)\to B$, we know that there is an $N$ such that $\forall n>N$, $\operatorname{d}(g(p_n),B)<|B|/2$, so that $g(p_n)\ne 0$. I made my comment general just to show that the definition in an arbitrary metric space is very similar to the definition in $\mathbb{R}$, but really you can just use the same "absolute value" bars in $\mathbb{C}$ that you would in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, it makes much more sense to frame this with sequences, but how does $d(g(p_n), b) < |B|/2$ imply $g(p_n) \neq 0$?  I'm sorry; I'm not able to see it, but I assume it's obvious.

Comment: If $g(p_n)=0$, then what is $\operatorname{d}(g(p_n),B)$?

Comment: I assume it's 0, but I don't feel fully comfortable saying that until I can prove it $d(x,0) = 0$ for any $x$. (Sorry if this is obvious.)

Comment: Ok, it seems that, instead, $d(0,B) = |B|$. Is that right? Is this provable or a definition?

Comment: Yes, it is $|B|$. I think that the modulus of a complex number $z=a+bi$ is defined as $z=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, which is the distance to $0$ in the complex plane, according to the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Ok, and this is just true by the definition of the norm? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I don't think I would call it "true", but rather the definition. You could define the modulus operator and distance in $\mathbb{C}$ so that $|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}/2$ and $\operatorname{d}(z_1, z_2) = |z_1-z_2|$, but that would not match the Euclidean distance when viewing the complex plane as isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is the usual metric on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: One last question that came up while trying to write this out: the only thing that impacts convergence is $n > N$ here, but the sequences $(f/g)(p_n)$ is not defined if $g(p_n) = 0$. Am I,  in effect, replacing $g$ with an equivalence sequence that is non-zero for $n \leq N$?

Comment: I'm not sure how Rudin defined $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x)$, but it's not a function on $E$ if $g(x)$ is zero anywhere on $E$. I would think that to be technically accurate he would have said something about $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x)$ being a function on $E \setminus \{x \in E | g(x)=0\}$. Then to be completely rigorous, it would probably be best to show that since $p$ is a limit point of $E$ and $g(p_n)\to B \ne 0$, we know that $p$ is a limit point of $E \setminus \{x \in E | g(x)=0\}$ also.